# Redirecting program output to file and shell

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a python program that makes some prints that I try to execute from the command line. I would like to redirect the output to a file and also see on the shell the prints. I tried `cmd > file`, `cmd >> file` and `cmd &> file`. But with these three commands, the prints are neither in the shell nor in the file. Why?

Comment: `cmd 2>&1 | tee file`

Comment: @glennjackman I guess that the referenced dup sums it up pretty well.  Nothing new to add here.  (Although finding a suitable dup took a while :)

Comment: @glennjackman Your shell gold badge would magically close this in a click.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-superpowers

Comment: @teaLeef Use `unbuffer` as mentioned in one of the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Write output to file and than read it with cat:

```
python myscript.py >> output.txt | cat output.txt
```